# Entity Framework Update model From Database with Oracle Error ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I am using EF 5.0 with Oracle. I have made a successful connection and until now had no issues updating the model from the db.

I recently encountered the a problem when trying to use the "Update Model From Database" option in the edmx file. I researched and I realize that the process is utilizing(eating up) all the available temp space on the server.
I then get the following error:   "ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace 'Space_Name'".

Unfortunately, this also happens when I am simply trying to refresh the Model from Database.

It appears that something may have changed in my project that causes this process to go into a loop. The server has about 800000 blocks and each block is 8192 which seems like plenty of space.

I hope someone can offer some direction as to the cause.

Thanks. YY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply explained I run out of processing space on the DB even though I have ~6GB to work with which seems to be more than enough.

After looking deeply into the issue I have come to realize that I am dealing with EF performance issue due to the size of my Database and its complexity.
The database I connect to has over 2000 tables. Although I am only asking for a fraction of them to be added to my model, there are factors that work against me and suck up all available space.

The largest is Database size - tables and relationships. The performance cost of increased schema size is nearly exponential. Hence the issue.

Suggestions for solution:

1. Read this carefully and understand the challenges (section 2.1): [Performance Considerations for Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)
2. If increasing the temporary space for your schema on the DB server is an option then do so and try to regenerate.
3. (Works for me) Use more than one EDMX file to generate your Model while giving the entities the same namespace and using the same connection.

All the best - YY.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3610894?start=15&tstart=0

Which simply says to upgrade to ODT+ODAC 12.1.0.2.1

I was on 12.1.0.1.2 and suffered of this issue for a database schema with a large number of tables (11k+ !!!). Same problem with EF5 and EF6. After upgrading ODT+ODAC, everything worked fine.